# Prevent fill-paragraph from breaking LaTeX citations in Org Mode

Tags: org-mode, elisp, regular-expressions, fill-paragraph

Stumbled upon the following problem.

Whenever `fill-paragraph` finds a LaTeX citation such as `\citep[][p. 10]{darwin1859}` (which appears as `(Darwin, 1859, p. 10)`), the paragraph gets broken like this:

```
Text text text text \citep[][p.
10]{darwin1859} text text text.
```

**How can I keep the citation intact, including the whitespace in `[p. 10]`?**

---

Now for what I've found so far.

There's a `fill-nobreak-predicate` hook that may contain functions that check whether `fill-paragraph` should skip certain regexps from being split (if I'm not mistaken).

I tried with this code but failed:

```
(defun my-nobreak-p ()
  (looking-at-p "\\\\citep.*\\}"))
(add-hook 'fill-nobreak-predicate #'my-nobreak-p)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you put on `fill-nobreak-predicate` should return non-nil *when point is at the space you don't want to break*.  So your `my-nobreak-p` doesn't help because that position is not followed by `\cite...` and hence doesn't match the regexp.

You can try something like

```
(defun my-nobreak-p ()
  (and (looking-at " *[0-9]")
       (looking-back "\\[p\\. *" (- (point) 5))))
(add-hook 'fill-nobreak-predicate #'my-nobreak-p)
```

Comment: Hello. Your function returns t at the right place but `fill-paragraph` still breaks the citations. Is there a way to explicitly tell `fill-paragraph` to avoid breaking it at all costs (e.g. moving the whole citation to a new line)?

Comment: I just fixed two details in my code (the name of the function, and the assumption that point is right before the space, whereas in practice it's normally right *after* the space).  Now it "does the right thing" in my test.

Comment: Excellent, it works great. Thank you! Now, in a general view, nobreak-p functions should return t when point is _after_, not right _at_ the space? Or maybe **both**, such is the case for your answer?

Comment: Obviously, I can never remember where point is supposed to be exactly.  And maybe there are also cases where point could be before the space. So it makes sense to just handle both cases at the same time.  It's generally easy to handle both cases with a simple `(save-excursion (skip-chars-backward " ") ...)`.