# org-fill-paragraph in the presence of LaTeX Formula

Tags: org-mode, latex, fill-paragraph

Consider the following piece of text

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
$$e^ix = cos(x) + i \dot sin(x)$$
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
```

The text is overly long so want to `org-fill-paragraph` it. Unfortunately `M-q` yields

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore $$e^ix = cos(x) + i \dot
sin(x)$$ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
```

which puts the formula within the text making it hard to read.

What can I do to make Emacs fill the text but keep the formula between `$$` on its own line?

I looked at [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/12419/30044) but couldn't make it work. I'm also hoping for a simpler solution for what I suspect is a common use case.

Comment: You can make each long line its own paragraph by inserting newlines before and after the formula, use `org-fill-paragraph` on each paragraph and then delete the extra newlines. Otherwise, the while thing is one paragraph and is formatted as such.

Comment: Thanks, that’s what I do now. Is there really nothing more elegant?

Comment: Nothing that I know of.

Comment: In your specific example, since the formula is a displayed formula in the LaTeX output, you might as well make it a separate paragraph in the Org mode file as well (IOW, embrace the extra newlines). But that wouldn't help e.g. with an inline formula.

Comment: In LaTeX output that will have the subtle difference that the next line will be treated as a new paragraph and thus be indented. This is only sometimes what you want :(