# `fill-paragraph` prevent breaking

Tags: fill-paragraph

I'm trying to prevent `fill-paragraph` from breaking a certain type of string:

```
<<dd_display: %9.3f abs(_b[2.rep78])>>
```

This is an inline Stata [dynamic tag](https://www.stata.com/manuals/rptdynamictags.pdf). The `<<dd_display:` and `>>` are fixed, the rest inside can change and be any length and contain any amount of whitespace.

I found [Prevent fill-paragraph from breaking LaTeX citations in Org Mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12392/prevent-fill-paragraph-from-breaking-latex-citations-in-org-mode) however it seems to rely on the space being in a fairly predictable place (within a certain number of positions from the start). I'm trying to generalize this to look backwards for `<<dd_display` without first finding a `>>`. This is my best shot so far, but it doesn't work.

```
(defun my-in-dd-display ()
  (< (looking-back "<<dd_display:") (- (match-end 0) (line-beginning-position))
     (looking-back ">>") (- (match-end 0) (line-beginning-position))))
(add-hook 'fill-nobreak-predicate #'my-in-dd-display)
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wanted [dalanicolai](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/26163/dalanicolai) to fix [his answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/78524/2370) but he didn't do it (see [my first](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/78493/fill-paragraph-prevent-breaking#comment131340_78524) and [my second](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/78493/fill-paragraph-prevent-breaking#comment131378_78524) comment).
So, I give here my own answer.

One surpresses filling if one finds the tag starter in a backward
search without finding the tag ender at first:

```el
(defun my-in-dd-display ()
  "Don't break lines in Inline Stata Dynamic Tags."
  (save-excursion
    (save-match-data
      (and (re-search-backward ">>\\|\\(<<dd_display:\\)" (line-beginning-position) t)
       (match-beginning 1)))))

(add-hook 'fill-nobreak-predicate #'my-in-dd-display)
```

The `re-search-backward` does the backward search that matches both, the tag-starter and the tag-end. The search stops if such a match is found. But only the tag-starter is grouped. The form `(and ... (match-beginning 1))` makes sure that the function returns non-nil if the tag-starter-group is matched and nil if the tag-end is matched.

Since the function is only a predicate it should not move point.
Avoiding a modification of the `match-data` is not required by the doc string of `fill-nobreak-predicate` but it is added as a precaution.

It is not clear from the question in which major mode you want to set up `my-in-dd-display` as fill predicate.

The standard way to add `my-in-dd-display` locally in certain major mode `my-major-mode` would be:

```el
(defun my-local-setup-in-dd-display ()
  "Activate `my-in-dd-display' locally in major modes except Orgmode."
  (add-hook 'fill-nobreak-predicate 'my-in-dd-display nil t))

(add-hook 'my-major-mode #'my-local-setup-in-dd-display)
```

Alternatively one could globally add `my-in-dd-display` to `fill-nobreak-predicate` for all modes except Orgmode as it is done in the first code snippet:

```el
(add-hook 'fill-nobreak-predicate 'my-in-dd-display)
```

Orgmode has a non-standard way setting up `fill-nobreak-predicate` in [`org-setup-filling`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/tree/lisp/org.el?h=release_9.6.7#n19156). It uses `setq-local` instead of `add-hook`.

So, to activate `my-in-dd-display` in Orgmode you need to set it with `setq` or `setq-local` in `org-mode-hook`:

```el
(defun my-org-setup-in-dd-display ()
  "Activate `my-in-dd-display' by `setq-local' as it is required for Orgmode."
  (unless (memq 'my-in-dd-display fill-nobreak-predicate)
    (setq-local fill-nobreak-predicate (cons 'my-in-dd-display fill-nobreak-predicate))))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'my-org-setup-in-dd-display)
```

Comment: Thanks - I think I was messing up something while trying your version from the comment - this works terrific! Would you mind explaining how it works? (The actual function, not the bit about activating it.)

Comment: @Josh I thought that the sentence "One surpresses filling if one finds the tag starter in a backward search without finding the tag ender at first" would describe it all. The `re-search-backward` does the backward search that matches both, the tag-starter and the tag-ender -- and the search stops if such a match is found. But only the tag-starter is grouped the the form `(and ... (match-beginning 1))` makes sure that the function only returns non-nil if that group is matched/filled/non-nil. (If that additional explanation helps I will add it to the answer below the code.)

Comment: @Josh Note, that this form of `my-in-dd-display` is even appropriate for `auto-fill-mode` since it works for incomplete input, i.e., tag-starters without tag-enders.

Comment: @Tobias I was waiting for Josh to provide an example for what he expected (also, before commenting on your comment). I tested your version, but I was not sure if that provided the desired behavior (it broke the line before the tag instead of after, and also Josh commented that it did not work). Anyway, thanks for your comments, I do appreciate them. Also, your answer is great, and very good that you decided to add it here. With your answer and the help of `edebug`, I finally understand what is going on :)

Comment: @Tobias Thanks for the explanation. I gathered what it was generally trying to do, but you explanation helped me how to the code was actually accomplishing it.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT

This answer provides an incorrect solution (see @Tobias his comments and answer), but I leave it here as an example of a faulty solution, and for the explanation why (via Tobias his comments and answer).

END EDIT

I don't really understand how the fill-paragraph algorithm works, for that you would probably have to study the source code. But after some trial and error, it seems like the following predicate function achieves what you want

```lisp
(defun fillp ()
  (prog1 (and (search-forward ">>" (line-end-position) t)
           (save-excursion
         (search-backward "<<dd_display:" (line-beginning-position) t))
           (forward-char))))

(add-hook 'fill-nobreak-predicate #'fillp)
```

The `fill-nobreak-predicate` docstring does mention that the function is called with the 'point at the place to be tested'. It seems that after executing the predicate, the point jumps back to the beginning of the word on which point ends (or the word before that place), after executing the predicate. Therefore, it seems that the 'save-excursion' and the 'forward-char' are also required.

Comment: Consider: ```(defun fillp ()
  "Don't break lines in Inline Stata Dynamic Tags."
  (save-excursion
    (save-match-data
      (and (re-search-backward ">>\\|\\(<<dd_display:\\)" (line-beginning-position) t)
       (match-beginning 1)))))```

Comment: These are great - but they fail if I have multiple `<<dd_display: ... >>` in a single paragraph. Can this be modified to search forward for `>>` before `<<dd_display` and search backwards for `<<dd_display:` before `>>`? E.g., if I have this string: `dfksfksf fskdfdklsfkdskf akfksalk akd akldka sjdkj kljdaksjk dla <<dd_display: abc def>> fdsjkfljds fjdksljflsd <<dd_display: fdskfds>> fsdjkflsd` with fill-column set to 80.

Comment: @Josh I am not sure what you mean, because to me, it looks like my code works fine on your example. Maybe you can add the example to your question, including the expected result? Thanks!

Comment: @dalanicolai Don't mess up current point though the first search for `>>`. The version in my comment above solves two problems: 1st it accepts partial input, i.e., it does not insert line breaks if the user has already typed in `<<dd_display:` before point without closing the tag yet. 2nd: Your code also avoids filling when there is a complete tag behind point, i.e., `xPoint here <<dd_display: complete tag here>>`.

Comment: @Josh Please try [your test](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/78493/fill-paragraph-prevent-breaking#comment131350_78524) with `my-in-dd-display` [from my answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/78562/2370). I did it and it worked for me.